# Tomcat gzip compressed javascript files throws error

Tags: tomcat, amazon-s3, metadata, gzip

I am using Tomcat as a web server by hosting web bundled files in ROOT folder of Tomcat server.

I have angular project and I am building my production build by using webpack. In production build, to all my files I am compressing into gzip.

for e.g.

main.bundle.js converts to main.bundle.js.gz

After conversion I change the file extension manually and remove .gz and save as .js.

After deployment, on browser files are loading but it throws error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I am uploading the same bundle files to AWS S3 bucket. After uploading files, in S3 console by manually adding metadata of files as content-encoding: gzip it works very fine.

I am struggling to understand do I need to add content-encoding metadata in each file manually before uploading it to Tomcat server? or I don't need to do that? or Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: You can't just remove the extension without doing something - they are still compressed files.  You found one option - force the `Content-Type`.  Another is to generate non-compressed files and serve them from S3 through [Cloudfront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html).

Comment: Agree. so point is how can I still set content-encoding gzip after removing .gz extension.

Comment: It depends on how you're uploading.  The AWS CLI [cp command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) allows you to specify the object meta data like content-type and so on.  All of the API's allow you to do the same though the details vary a bit.